# How to update a value inside mongodb with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to update a value inside mogoodb array but is the problem
database?

```json
    "TempChannels": [{
        "user": "299481590445113345",
        "channel": "794869948878159884",
        "settings": []
    }, {
        "user": "583363766750806043",
        "channel": "795004103998308352",
        "settings": []
    }],
```

The part of the code that should update the user:

```js
Data.TempChannels[0].user = Target.id
Data.save().catch(er => console.log(er))
```

Also, no error appears when I run the code. and when i console the data it returns a user which has updated but it is not actually saved in mongodb!
code

```js
Data.save().then(() => console.log(Data.TempChannels[0].user))
```

this is the whole data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ff0cd1ee3d9fd2d40d82d23"
    },
    "TempChannels": [{
        "user": "299481590445113345",
        "channel": "795014692522295326",
        "settings": []
    }, {
        "user": "583363766750806043",
        "channel": "795015273060892753",
        "settings": []
    }],
    "Guild": "704158258201624657",
    "Stats": "true",
    "ChannelID": "795014681664290826",
    "ParentID": "795014680556994610",
    "LogChannelID": "795014683601010709",
    "TempControlChannelID": "795014682518749274",
    "DefaultSettings": {
        "limit": null,
        "name": null,
        "bitrate": null,
        "copyperms": null
    },
    "__v": 2
}
```

I'm filtering the data by Guild

Comment: I think it is changed in this console.log Data.save().then(() => console.log(Data.TempChannels[0].user)) because you are logging the data which you just updated in your variable "Data" but it is not saved to mongoose and that's why it appears here to be updated but in fact it is not, as it is not saved properly.
 Are you using mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if you are using mongoose to connect MongoDB, the 
Use markModified("updated field name")

Data.TempChannels[0].user = Target.id
Data.markModified('TempChannels');
Data.save().catch(er => console.log(er))
```

Comment: not working and i got this error
```
MongoError: Cannot create field 'user' in element {TempChannels: [ { user: "299481590445113345", channel: "795014692522295326", settings: [] } ]}
```

Comment: can you try with Data.markModified('TempChannels') ??

Comment: enjoy..!! happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mongoose, there is a method that will allow to update the content of existing data

```
const res = await Person.replaceOne({ _id: 24601 }, { name: 'Jean Valjean' });
res.n; // Number of documents matched
res.nModified; // Number of documents modified
```

Comment: Can you explain your code more? what is Person can u read my question again, I update somethings

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mongoose, you can update the record by doing something similar to this:

```
SchemaName.update({Guild: 'Guild Value Here'}, {$set: { "TempChannels[0].user" : "%newvalue%"}})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log.error(err);
    
});
```

You should replace schemaName with the name of your schema if you are using mongoose, and in case you are not using it, I think it would be better for you to start using it.

Comment: this is the log({ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }) and nothing change in the database , i'm using  schema